# Visual Studio Code, Anaconda Virtual Environment, specific projects?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, path, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

can anyone help me understand using conda environment with visual studio code? I had activate the virtual environment (imageprocessing) with this:

```
conda activate imageprocessing
```

and the terminal seem to have been on virtual environment, so there's look like no problem with the PATH, it looks like this.

```
(imageprocessing) ../users/[project_folder_somewhere]
```

But when I open visual studio code and activate the kernel used for opening Notebooks there, exactly with the python from imageprocessing virtual environment, I keep needed to install the previously forged library, for example, Pillow. Which part that doesn't work out? Did I install Pillow package redundantly if I keep doing this? Does visual code doesn't integrated that well with conda even though it has been connected through the path? I used this feature for opening .ipynb files on Visual Studio Code because browser-based Jupyter Notebooks are too slow and messy directory than if using this (or so I thought?).

Comment: Do you mean that you used this conda environment in Jupyter in VS Code, but the module cannot be used? Have you selected this conda environment in the upper right corner of Jupyter? Please provide us with relevant screenshots and problems shown in VS Code.

Comment: @JillCheng Yes. I have selected the needed environment on the right side of the jupyter and activate it with native Visual Code terminal, but the library seem to not be updated at all. The error window says some library doesn't exists which actually I've been forged before in my previous work in that environment. Do you know what's wrong with that?

Comment: -What is “my previous work in that environment”? Is it the same conda environment called "imageprocessing"?

Comment: @JillCheng Yes, I've done another project with Visual Code Jupyter Notebook before with the same environment I want to use now. What exactly happened? Can you elaborate it in the answer so I can understand how this VS Code Jupyter Notebook and Anaconda works?

Comment: ok, I will take the module "pillow" as an example to explain the use of conda environment in Jupyter in VS Code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VS Code, when we use different python environments, the locations where the modules are installed are different. Therefore, we need to be clear which python environment we are currently using. (We could check it with the command "`python --version`" in the VS Code terminal.)

When we use the conda environment, it comes with python, so we can use "pip" to install modules, or "conda" to install modules. The modules it installs are stored in: "`...\anaconda3\envs\conda-name\lib\site-packages`".

The command "`pip show pillow`" checks the installation position of the module:

[image]

In addition, after the installation is complete, it still shows that the module cannot be found. I noticed that there is a problem with the file name here. We need to rename "PIL" to "pillow", or use "import PIL"

[image]

Reference: [conda-environment in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_global-virtual-and-conda-environments).

Add:

[image]

Comment: I thought pip and conda is two different thing that cannot be installed together since they will conflict each other libraries. Pip install pillow and conda install pillow is same stuff done in different places right? Why PIL and Pillow shown different folder though, I just recognized this

Comment: @Dean Debrio -Both "pip" and "conda" are module installation tools. In the same python environment, the modules they install are stored in the same location. For module installation, the result is the same, but the installation method is different.

Comment: @Dean Debrio -The sources of "pip" and "conda" download modules are sometimes different, but the downloaded modules are stored in "...\lib\site-packages" in the python environment.

Comment: so, as long as my python library is in PATH, no matter which module installation tools I used, the library should always be able to be read from my visual code jupyter notebook libraries, except if there's a naming errors? And to make sure my library used in visual studio code, I should always check used libraries on the right side of the panel, right?

Comment: @Dean Debrio -Can I understand that the "library" on the right side of the panel you said is the Python environment? After we select the python environment where the module is installed, we can import and use the modules in this environment.

Comment: yes the "library part" we sought is written as ` Python 3.8.5 64-bit('imageprocessing':conda):idle` right? So what I should do is just select this and activate it through native Visual Code terminal, right?

Comment: @Dean Debrio -Yes, please pay attention to the python used by the VS Code terminal when installing the module to avoid it using other python environments. (like the screenshot of my answer, the terminal is in the conda environment and is active.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228191/discussion-between-dean-debrio-and-jill-cheng).

Comment: @Dean Debrio -Do you have any other doubts about this thread? We can discuss it here because these records will help others who have the same problem.

Comment: Looks like that was the problem, I try to 'conda activate' but the terminal seem to not changed like what I see in your picture or windows command prompt. So typing conda forge in this position will install the PIL somewhere I don't know. Do you know what happened here? Also, if I activate it through my command prompt terminal, will it actually do the same?

Comment: @Dean Debrio -Please try to enter "conda activate conda-name" in the terminal, or try to kill the current VS Code terminal and then use the shortcut key Ctrl+Shift+` to open a new terminal, it will automatically enter the currently selected python environment (shown in the lower left corner of VSCode of).

Comment: @Dean Debrio  -The command "pip --version" can check the source of pip, and the module is installed in this location.

Comment: Done, its still "PS [some directory]" stuff

Comment: I've used the pip method, I found where the pillow library is and its on anaconda's directory anaconda3\lib\site-packages , But I can't find PIL library which I've used before in previous project, on the same environment.

Comment: @Dean Debrio  -Powershell does not activate the conda environment by default. It is recommended that you use the cmd terminal. (Use _"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\cmd.exe",_ in "settings.json")

Comment: @Dean Debrio  -"Anaconda3\lib\site-packages" means that the module is stored in conda's base environment, not in the "imageprocessing" conda environment you created.

Comment: @Dean Debrio -Which conda environment do you want to use? Which environment has the module you need? (1. Please elect the environment in the lower left corner of VS Code, 2. then open a new VS Code terminal, 3. Open Jupyter and select the same python environment.)

Comment: Looks like when I do the previous project, I install all the needed libraries on the 'base' environment, not on the 'imageprocessing' environment, because the terminal used in VS Code previously was PowerShell that you told me it doesn't activate the conda automatically from the PATH like cmd. Problem solved, I can use the library with this environment. One more question, does the usual windows cmd is different than native visual code cmd prompt? Does activating it outside visual code would activate the kernel as well?

Comment: And does installing multiple python on one environment will disturb the package installed there? Sometimes I need to use 3.6, should I just built new environment?

Comment: @Dean Debrio  -The cmd terminal and powershell terminal in VS Code are the corresponding terminals integrated from the system, so they are essentially the same. As for the python environment, too much python is not easy to manage. It is recommended that you use a [virtual environment](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_global-virtual-and-conda-environments). The modules installed in this environment will be stored in the project. Checking the modules is more intuitive.